# How to bound JVM with a fixed memory limit?

Tags: java, jvm

I want to bound JVM with a fixed memory limit. Can any one help me how to do this ?

More specifically, I want that my code can use max 1024 mb memory space and my JVM has to initially block that much of memory.

Another thing, I have 4 GB memory but my JVM shows only 878 MB memory. Why ?

I got it using: `Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime()` and `runtime.totalMemory()/(1024*1024)`

Why C has not this kind of issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java won't use more memory than it needs, if you have a hello world program, it won't use 1 GB no matter what you set the maximum to.

In C, memory is either used, or freed.  There is not other state for memory.  In Java, you have memory which has a string reference, a soft reference, a weak reference and no reference. The maximum memory you determines when to clean up memory and whether soft/weak refernces get cleaned up.

The problem with C memory is you have to know when memory is no longer used, which can result in memory leaks and/or additional complexity which is exposed to the developer.  Java doesn't have these problems as it has managed memory.

C programs also have the problem they can grow until you run out of memory+swap. For a well behaved program this is not a problem, but its another thing the developer needs to worry about because he doesn't know how much memory the machine the program might be run on might have.

Answer (score 0):

you can run 'java' with the following options

-xms minimum memory size
-xxs max memory size

Comment: -Xmx is used for maximize heap memory